# hasAttribute should return true even when the attribute is not explicitly specified, but doesn't

Tags: javascript, attributes, w3c

From W3C - hasAttribute - Returns true when an attribute with a given name is specified on this element or has a default value, false otherwise.

Now, all elements have a default class attribute as an empty string as mentioned [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Attr)

So, if I apply `hasAttribute('class')` or `hasAttribute('className')` on an element on which I haven't explicitly specified the class attribute, it should even then return true, but it doesn't in Firefox and Chrome. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of:

"However, empty default attributes do not appear in the DOM tree — only those attributes which have an actual value (either a specific default value in the DTD, or an explicit value) appear in the DOM; this is referred to as having an effective value. "

you can read it [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Attr)

Comment: The "you can read it here" link is no longer valid.